# Sum area of specific poly attributes within raster grid cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, aggregation

I have a polygon layer (A) containing several different land use types (road, building, etc).  I also have a different GIS layer (B), a raster of NLCD land use/land cover.  I would like to sum/calculate the area of certain attributes in A (say roads) within each grid cell of B, to use in a comparison. Both layers are in the same projection.

How does one go about doing this in ArcMap?

Edit: Here are pics to help understand:

The polygon layer:

[image]

The polygon attribute table:

[image]

The raster layer sitting on top of the area of interest:

[image]

The end result I desire is another raster, with the same footprint as my red/pink raster, that has a value of the area of the 'road' polygon within each grid cell.

Comment: Zonal Statistics as Table http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000 might help here but it wont give you the area of each class (raster value) if you're only looking for the area categorized by raster value it might be better to make your land cover into polygons and overlay then use Summary Statistics with a case fields of polygon 'A' FID and GRID_CODE to see your class/area breakdown for each input polygon. Can you show us a picture of what you've got?

Answer (score 5):

You can select the feature of interest (e.g. roads) and run [Zonal Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) with a "SUM" statistic. This will produce your desired raster output. Repeat for any other features of interest.

Comment: I have a Polygon and a taster, not two rasters. Will update with picture in a second.

Comment: @traggatmot You will note in the documentation that the zone parameter accepts vector data. It essentially does an internal polygon to raster operation prior to running the Tabulate Area.

Comment: @traggatmot although tool can handle polygons, internally it converts them to raster. Cell size defines the accuracy of output, thus I suggest to convert polygons to raster anyway, to better understand limitations

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear - does the solution Aaron proposes still work?

Comment: This solution does not work, as far as I can tell, as I do not want an table as output, but a raster.

Comment: Convert pink to points. Points to raster using point I'd. Raster to polygon. Intersect with roads. Summarise area per tiny rectangles. Update small polygons through join. Compute ratio. Convert to raster, expected values in range 0..1

Comment: @traggatmot Your original post has changed significantly. I've edited my post to keep up with yours.